# Thymeleaf: Absolute References in css-File

Tags: css, url, thymeleaf

I've seen questions with answers that recommend to convert the absolute paths to relative paths, but this isn't possible for me as my HTML-files are stored in various directories and use a template where one line refers to the CSS. So the `fragments.html` starts like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head th:fragment="common_header(title)">
  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
:
```

The actual HTML looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head th:replace="fragments :: common_header('List Items')">
  <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script th:src="@{/js/rss/list.js}"></script>
:
```

And now `/css/style.css`:

```
.item-subject::before {
  content: url("/images/new.png");
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

With context path and all it's obvious that this doesn't work. But, what can I do? I mean the `th:href` makes the `link` point to a valid resource, so now also the content of the CSS should be thymeleafed somehow.

It's clear that the `content`-line has to contain the magic, but how do I do make all of that work?

Answer (score 1):

You [can parse css files with thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html#template-modes), just like you can parse html files.  Thymeleaf 3 specifically has a CSS mode.  You'll have to set up controllers just like you would for html files ([here is a sample project](https://github.com/jmiguelsamper/thymeleaf3-template-modes-example)), but after that you can use url expression directly in your css, like this:

```
.item-subject::before {
  content: url([[@{/images/new.png}]]);
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Which should resolve any problems you're having with absolute urls.